# Can't see LDAP users on CognosBI site

Tags: ldap, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am using ApacheDS for a ldapserver. 
I set it up and can connect with Apache dashboard but not another 3rd party app(Cognos BI).
I have the following configuration:
uid=admin,ou=system     password: admin

```
IBM Cognos V11
Cognos Setting for clarity: (Under Security ->authentication):
Type: LDAP - General default values
Namespace ID: Test (also tried same name as the LDAP server)
Host and port: 123.456.789:10389
Base DN: ou=system (default apacheds server)
user lookup: uid=${userID} or just ${userID}
Bind user and pass: admin/admin
Other settings are all default
```

When I tested the connection it works on Cognos Config. 
When I go to cognos BI website i can select the LDAP server and log in SUCCESSFULLY.
However, when i go to the LDAP group i dont see the dozen of users i added.
When I also go to "cognos" group and add users to a particular group i still cant find or see anyone under my new LDAP.

What is going on? I tried admin still no good.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you change "Use Bind Credentials for Search" to True? Did you define the group mappings? for us, its defined as "groupofnames". Did you define Member? for us its "member". Can you provide a snapshot of the LDAP config from the Cognos Configuration?

Comment: I did manage to get the test-connection to work and i can see the namespace on Cognos website login. HOWEVER, i dont know how to login?

I have ldap://XYZ:10389/uid=Admin,ou=CognosUsers,dc=example,dc=com
path for User Admin.
I dont know what to use to login as the username - I tried Admin/Admin and got "The provided credentials are invalid. Please type your credentials for authentication."

I tried CognosUsers/Admin too but no good... is there something i am missing? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following step by step is similar to the one I already provided.  This one covers the setup again, and the proper search path and identity mappings.

http://www.cognossource.com/apacheds-ldap-ibm-cognos/

Comment: I did that to a T but can't pass the "Test Connection". I DID use ou=system only (where the default admin is) and it works. I ended up copy and pasting uid=admin and change the uid/sn to "JoeS" etc. and i see them in Cognos. 

Ideally i want to use a better structure but that is not happening. I think something is weird with the namespace BECAUSE when i replaced "uid=Admin,ou=CognosUsers,dc=example,dc=com" with "uid=Admin,ou=system"   the test passes....